# How to rename an application server in WebSphere Application Server 6.0.2.23

Tags: websphere

We are repurposing an application server running WebSphere 6.0.2.23.  I would like to rename the various application server to better reflect its new role.

How can you rename an application server?

It seems like wsadmin can do it, but I'm struggling with the object hierarchy.

Answer (score 4):

[IBM Sample Scripts](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/samples/SampleScripts.html)

download:

> ConfigScripts.zip

from command line execute:

```
/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/bin/ws_ant.sh \
-profileName AppSrv01 \
-buildfile exportImport.xml \
-logfile rename.log \
-DoldServerName=server1 \
-DnewServerName=server2 \
-DnodeName=yourNode01 changeServerName
```

[source](http://biounix.blogspot.com/2009/01/how-to-change-websphere-app-server-name.html)

Comment: An easier option if you are running a clustered set up is to create a new cluster member with the required name. Delete the old server and keep note of all the ports for the original server and state them as the port numbers for this new server. "Server1" is a notorius name in WebSphere!!!

Answer (score 1):

An easier option if you are running a clustered set up is to create a new cluster member with the required name.

Delete the old server and keep note of all the ports for the original server and state them as the port numbers for this new server(if you need the same port numbers)

If you are using a non-clustered environment, then create a template out of the existing server. Create your new server based on that template so you have all the required config. Now like earlier change the port numbers back to the original ones.

**If the change in port numbers are not a problem for you then you don't need to perform that step.**

HTH

Manglu