# How to rename an WebSphere Application server 7

Tags: websphere, commerce

Good day everyone.

How can i change application server name (server1 by default) in dmgr environment?

I've found similar topic - [How to rename an application server in WebSphere Application Server 6.0.2.23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279293/how-to-rename-an-application-server-in-websphere-application-server-6-0-2-23)

and tried method mentoined there:

```
/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/bin/ws_ant.sh \
-profileName AppSrv01 \
-buildfile exportImport.xml \
-logfile rename.log \
-DoldServerName=server1 \
-DnewServerName=server2 \
-DnodeName=yourNode01 changeServerName
```

server renames, and i can stop it with newservername, but when i try to start it server unavailable with newservername, configuration does not saving some how

Can someone please shed more light on this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a command useable from the command prompt called renameNode.sh(.bat) to modify the node name of a federated server.

Navigate to your profile's root directory. (Usually something like: /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/bin on unix servers)

Syntax: renameNode.sh   
              renameNode.bat

Launching this command results in the following actions:

1. Connects to the Deployment Manager.
2. Stops all Servers.
3. Changes the node configuration on the Deployment Manger.
4. Synchronizes the node.

Alternately, there is a big Python library here:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/samples/SampleScripts.html
which may have a rename function, not sure.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply WPrecht, but i'm looking for way to change server name ("Server1" by default) not node name.